# How to retrieve a hidden field from a combobox?

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have a table of users (tbl_users) and a table of user roles (tbl_list_user_roles).  In the tbl_users I have stored an ID (Role_ID) for the role assigned to the user.  In the tbl_list_user_roles I have several roles that populate a combobox (snippet follows):

```
st = conn.createStatement();
String QueryString3 = "SELECT ID, RoleName FROM tbl_list_user_roles WHERE Active = true ORDER BY RoleRank DESC";
ResultSet rs3 = st.executeQuery(QueryString3);
while (rs3.next()) {
    cbo_Role.addItem(new TypeEntry_Role(rs3.getInt(1), rs3.getString(2)));          
}
rs3.close();
```

The results of the query look like this (sorry, can't get the columns to line up neatly):

```
ID     RoleRank   RoleName   Active  
7       100       None       true  
1        99       Viewer     true  
4        30       Reviewer   true  
3        20       Assigner   true  
2        10       Analyst    true  
5       -50       Admin      true  
6       -99       Developer  true
```

And here's its associated class:

```
class TypeEntry_Role {
    private int value;
    private String label;

    public TypeEntry_Role(int ID, String RoleName) {
        this.value = ID;
        this.label = RoleName;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

Here's the code I'm attempting to use to set the selected row in the combobox for the Role_ID in tbl_Users (second column of the selectedRow):

```
cbo_Role.setSelectedIndex((int) table_Users.getValueAt(selectedRow, 2) -1 );
```

The problem is the .getValueAt returns the **Role_ID** from tbl_users.  What I need for setSelectedIndex is the **index** for the Role_ID.  For example, if the Role_ID is 4 (Reviewer), I need to set the SelectedIndex to 2.  The code as shown sets the SelectedIndex to 4, which displays "Analyst".

So, I think I need a way to get the index for the selectedRow rather than the ValueAt.  I suppose I could iterate through the contents of the combobox and find the entry that has the Role_ID that matches the ID (hidden) column and then use that index.  However, I don't know a way to access the **ID** (value) of the combobox.  My attempts to do so return the **RoleName** (label).

Perhaps there's a more direct approach.  If so, that would be favorable.

I'm relatively new to Java, coming from MS-Access.  Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You would iterate through the entries in the combobox, and (this is what I *think* you are missing:) call `getValue()` on them to get the id value (assuming the id is held in this field), and then highlight the cell that holds the correct id value.

Your "answer" shows that you're calling `getValue()` on a JComboBox, something that really doesn't make sense. Your TypeEntry_Role on the other hand **has** a `getValue()` method, and this of course is the one you should use! For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cbo_Role.getItemCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " item: " + cbo_Role.getItemAt(i).getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  That's exactly what I needed.